# make a $.post before form action takes place

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form and when the user clicks the submit button I want to run a separate PHP script before the form-action (going to the next page) gets executed.

Of course I can stop the form-action with `evt.preventDefault();` and then I can fire my jquery `$.post` call but then I cannot 'resume' or undo this preventDefault call, as far as I can see.

So what is the best way to execute a script that process some information after a user clicks the submit button BUT before the user gets redirected to the next page defined in the form action tag?

(Of course I could just carry over the data and perform whatever I want on the next page – but in this case, I would like to keep it separate).

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var posted = false;
$('form').on('submit', function(ev) {
    if ( ! posted ) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $.post(url).done(function() {
            posted = true;
            $('form').trigger('submit');
        });
    }
    posted = false;
});
```

Or more succinct, using [extra parameters](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#example-3):

```
$('form').on('submit', function(ev, posted) {
    if ( ! posted ) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $.post(url).done(function() {
            $('form').trigger('submit', [true]);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your $.post call can be run synchronously, so the form would not submit until you've got a response from the server.
2. You can submit the form programmatically, perhaps in your callback function.

Answer (score 1):

prevent default on `form`, then run `post`, on success of `post`, target the form by id and use .submit();

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

    $.post({
     url:'url',
     success:function() {
        $('#formid').submit()
     }
     });

});
```

Comment: wouldn't this be an endless loop?  prevent default on form submit - then submit on success - which enters the same event handler again?

Comment: Added preventDefault to a click handler so when $(form).submit() hits the call to post won't be run again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go head with your evt.preventDefault().
2. Make an $.ajax() call to run your php script.
3. In the $.ajax() success/failure callback, check the output of the php script you want to run, and accordingly make a $.post call (or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can always hook the click event, and do your stuff.
When you are done you just do $(form).submit();

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DNTYg/)

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // do your ajax stuff here.. $.post().
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just use the native submit function instead of jQuery's submit() which goes through the event handler again

```
$('form').submit(function(e){ // change form to your form id
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = this; // store this form in variable
    $.post('/echo/html/',data,function(d){ // your post function
       el.submit(); // trigger native submit function in success callback
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5vEsu/)

Answer (score -2):

In your form tag, add `onsubmit="myfunction()"`

Comment: what do you think the `on("submit"...` is doing?

Comment: HUH? I do not have an answer... The OP is using onsubmit and you are using an inline event which is bad practice.